# MySQL выбор записи по подстроке из текста

Tags: php, mysql, select

Доброй ночи. Есть вопрос.
Дан текст:

> Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что постоянный
>   количественный рост и сфера нашей активности представляет собой
>   интересный эксперимент проверки существенных финансовых и
>   административных условий. Повседневная практика показывает, что
>   сложившаяся структура организации влечет за собой процесс внедрения и
>   модернизации позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных
>   задач. Задача организации, в особенности же укрепление и развитие
>   структуры в значительной степени обуславливает создание дальнейших
>   направлений развития. Не следует, однако забывать, что дальнейшее
>   развитие различных форм деятельности в значительной степени
>   обуславливает создание позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении
>   поставленных задач. Разнообразный и богатый опыт консультация с
>   широким активом представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки
>   системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям.
>   Повседневная практика показывает, что сложившаяся структура
>   организации играет важную роль в формировании позиций, занимаемых
>   участниками в отношении поставленных задач.
>
> Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что начало повседневной
>   работы по формированию позиции требуют определения и уточнения
>   соответствующий условий активизации. Идейные соображения высшего
>   порядка, а также постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей
>   активности позволяет оценить значение новых предложений.
>
> Таким образом постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности
>   позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке новых предложений.
>   Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также сложившаяся структура
>   организации представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки систем
>   массового участия. Не следует, однако забывать, что сложившаяся
>   структура организации обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов)
>   участие в формировании направлений прогрессивного развития.
>
> Равным образом дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности играет
>   важную роль в формировании системы обучения кадров, соответствует
>   насущным потребностям. Таким образом сложившаяся структура организации
>   требуют от нас анализа дальнейших направлений развития. Задача
>   организации, в особенности же укрепление и развитие структуры
>   способствует подготовки и реализации дальнейших направлений развития.
>   Разнообразный и богатый опыт сложившаяся структура организации влечет
>   за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации новых предложений.
>
> Повседневная практика показывает, что постоянное
>   информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности
>   представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки систем массового
>   участия. Задача организации, в особенности же новая модель
>   организационной деятельности играет важную роль в формировании
>   существенных финансовых и административных условий.

И есть таблица вида

> id, keyword, user_id
>
> 1   "Пример" 2 
> 2   "значимость проблем" 2
>   
> 3   "богатый опыт" 3 
> 4   "количественный тест" 2

как видно записи 2, 3 keyword есть в тексте.
На практике таких записей около 30 тысяч и текст прилично длинее примера, так что получить все записи через SELECT с бд и потом в цикле искать для каждой вхождение подстроки в текст не предлагать.
Пробовал его преобразить в различные regexp и по REGEX искать в бд вида `[(слово\s*)|(слово2\s*)|(etc\s*)]{2,}`
и прочие подобные махинации с регулярками но они так ничего и не дали, возвращались либо все записи крилицей, либо ни одной.
Есть ли способ без костылей достать все эти записи у которых keyword является подстрокой данного текста?

UPDATE

```
SELECT * from subscribe_keywords WHERE keyword REGEXP '/(Значимость\s*)|(этих\s*)|(проблем\s*)|(настолько\s*)|(очевидна,\s*)|(постоянный\s*)|(количественный\s*)|(рост\s*)|(сфера\s*)|(нашей\s*)|(активности\s*)|(представляет\s*)|(собой\s*)|(интересный\s*)|(эксперимент\s*)|(проверки\s*)|(существенных\s*)|(финансовых\s*)|(административных\s*)|(условий\.\s*)|(Повседневная\s*)|(практика\s*)|(показывает,\s*)|(сложившаяся\s*)|(структура\s*)|(организации\s*)|(влечет\s*)|(собой\s*)|(процесс\s*)|(внедрения\s*)|(модернизации\s*)|(позиций,\s*)|(занимаемых\s*)|(участниками\s*)|(отношении\s*)|(поставленных\s*)|(задач\.\s*)|(Задача\s*)|(организации,\s*)|(особенности\s*)|(укрепление\s*)|(развитие\s*)|(структуры\s*)|(значительной\s*)|(степени\s*)|(обуславливает\s*)|(создание\s*)|(дальнейших\s*)|(направлений\s*)|(развития\.\s*)|(следует,\s*)|(однако\s*)|(забывать,\s*)|(дальнейшее\s*)|(развитие\s*)|(различных\s*)|(форм\s*)|(деятельности\s*)|(значительной\s*)|(степени\s*)|(обуславливает\s*)|(создание\s*)|(позиций,\s*)|(занимаемых\s*)|(участниками\s*)|(отношении\s*)|(поставленных\s*)|(задач\.\s*)|(Разнообразный\s*)|(богатый\s*)|(опыт\s*)|(консультация\s*)|(широким\s*)|(активом\s*)|(представляет\s*)|(собой\s*)|(интересный\s*)|(эксперимент\s*)|(проверки\s*)|(системы\s*)|(обучения\s*)|(кадров,\s*)|(соответствует\s*)|(насущным\s*)|(потребностям\.\s*)|(Повседневная\s*)|(практика\s*)|(показывает,\s*)|(сложившаяся\s*)|(структура\s*)|(организации\s*)|(играет\s*)|(важную\s*)|(роль\s*)|(формировании\s*)|(позиций,\s*)|(занимаемых\s*)|(участниками\s*)|(отношении\s*)|(поставленных\s*)|(задач\.Значимость\s*)|(этих\s*)|(проблем\s*)|(настолько\s*)|(очевидна,\s*)|(начало\s*)|(повседневной\s*)|(работы\s*)|(формированию\s*)|(позиции\s*)|(требуют\s*)|(определения\s*)|(уточнения\s*)|(соответствующий\s*)|(условий\s*)|(активизации\.\s*)|(Идейные\s*)|(соображения\s*)|(высшего\s*)|(порядка,\s*)|(также\s*)|(постоянный\s*)|(количественный\s*)|(рост\s*)|(сфера\s*)|(нашей\s*)|(активности\s*)|(позволяет\s*)|(оценить\s*)|(значение\s*)|(новых\s*)|(предложений\.Таким\s*)|(образом\s*)|(постоянный\s*)|(количественный\s*)|(рост\s*)|(сфера\s*)|(нашей\s*)|(активности\s*)|(позволяет\s*)|(выполнять\s*)|(важные\s*)|(задания\s*)|(разработке\s*)|(новых\s*)|(предложений\.\s*)|(Идейные\s*)|(соображения\s*)|(высшего\s*)|(порядка,\s*)|(также\s*)|(сложившаяся\s*)|(структура\s*)|(организации\s*)|(представляет\s*)|(собой\s*)|(интересный\s*)|(эксперимент\s*)|(проверки\s*)|(систем\s*)|(массового\s*)|(участия\.\s*)|(следует,\s*)|(однако\s*)|(забывать,\s*)|(сложившаяся\s*)|(структура\s*)|(организации\s*)|(обеспечивает\s*)|(широкому\s*)|(кругу\s*)|((специалистов)\s*)|(участие\s*)|(формировании\s*)|(направлений\s*)|(прогрессивного\s*)|(развития\.Равным\s*)|(образом\s*)|(дальнейшее\s*)|(развитие\s*)|(различных\s*)|(форм\s*)|(деятельности\s*)|(играет\s*)|(важную\s*)|(роль\s*)|(формировании\s*)|(системы\s*)|(обучения\s*)|(кадров,\s*)|(соответствует\s*)|(насущным\s*)|(потребностям\.\s*)|(Таким\s*)|(образом\s*)|(сложившаяся\s*)|(структура\s*)|(организации\s*)|(требуют\s*)||(анализа\s*)|(дальнейших\s*)|(направлений\s*)|(развития\.\s*)|(Задача\s*)|(организации,\s*)|(особенности\s*)|(укрепление\s*)|(развитие\s*)|(структуры\s*)|(способствует\s*)|(подготовки\s*)|(реализации\s*)|(дальнейших\s*)|(направлений\s*)|(развития\.\s*)|(Разнообразный\s*)|(богатый\s*)|(опыт\s*)|(сложившаяся\s*)|(структура\s*)|(организации\s*)|(влечет\s*)|(собой\s*)|(процесс\s*)|(внедрения\s*)|(модернизации\s*)|(новых\s*)|(предложений\.Повседневная\s*)|(практика\s*)|(показывает,\s*)|(постоянное\s*)|(информационно-пропагандистское\s*)|(обеспечение\s*)|(нашей\s*)|(деятельности\s*)|(представляет\s*)|(собой\s*)|(интересный\s*)|(эксперимент\s*)|(проверки\s*)|(систем\s*)|(массового\s*)|(участия\.\s*)|(Задача\s*)|(организации,\s*)|(особенности\s*)|(новая\s*)|(модель\s*)|(организационной\s*)|(деятельности\s*)|(играет\s*)|(важную\s*)|(роль\s*)|(формировании\s*)|(существенных\s*)|(финансовых\s*)|(административных\s*)|(условий\.\s*)/im';
```

вот такой запрос получается на тот текст что писал выше. А это keyword в таблице: 
 Пример,Продукт,значимость проблем,богатый опыт,количественный тест. Вернуть должно значимость проблем,богатый опыт а возвращает по этому запросу всё!

Comment: Попробуй просто `/(слово\s*)|(слово\s*)|(слово\s*)/im`.

Comment: Проверил такое регулярное выражение на тексте который писал в посте.  Если несколько слов до 5 то возвращает все keyword где есть одно из слов. То есть для строк слово1 слово2, слово2, слово3 слово 4, слово2 слово4 - должно возратить только строки слово1 слово2, слово2, слово2 слово4 для регулярки /(слово1\s*)|(слово2\s*)|(слово4\s*)/im на практике регулярка возвращает все вхождения даже если одно из слов найдено.